# How to balance Spark DataFrame data before partitionBy output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

I have DataFrame with geospatial data. I want to partitionBy it by columns: data source `id` and `quadkeys`.

The main goal is to have minimum number of files not bigger than certain size at one hand.

On the other hand, I want to keep my in memory partitions optimized (if that would be to big I may encounter out of memory exception).

In other words, I have `qk` = 0,1,2,3, and next number of records per each `quadkey`: `0 (1000), 1 (1000), 2 (10000), 3(100000). At output files I desire to have next files (not more than 5000 records on each): 0 (1000) 1 (1000) 2_1 (5000) 2_2 (5000) 3_1 (5000) ... 3_10 (5000)`

As a solution I build a distribution lookup and than salt. I am wondering what would be better solution for this.

```
val MAX_PARTITION_ROWS = 3000000

val pid = "sourceid"
val qk = "qk"
val distributionDf: Array[((Int, String), Int)] = stage.
  select(col(pid), col(qk), lit(1L) as "cnt").
  groupBy(pid,qk).
  agg(sum("cnt") as "sum").
  rdd.map(r=>((r.getInt(0), r.getString(1))->r.getLong(2).toInt)).collect
LOG.info(s"QK distribution\nQK |PID |Count |Partitions number")
LOG.info(s"${distributionDf.sortBy(-_._2).map(x=>s"${x._1._2} |${x._1._1} | ${x._2} | ${x._2/MAX_PARTITION_ROWS}").mkString("\n")}")

val r = scala.util.Random
val distributionMap = distributionDf map { case (k, v) => k -> (v/MAX_PARTITION_ROWS+1) }toMap
val saltUdf = udf((pid: Int, qk: String) => {
  val dev = distributionMap.getOrElse((pid, qk), 1)
  r.nextInt(dev)
})

val partitionsNumber = if (distributionMap.isEmpty) 1 else distributionMap.values.sum

stage.withColumn("salt", saltUdf(col(pid),col(qk)))
  .repartition(partitionsNumber, col(pid), col(qk), col("salt"))
  .drop("salt")
  .write.partitionBy(pid, qk)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", (MAX_PARTITION_ROWS*1.2).toInt)
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .save(destUrl)
```

Comment: if you give sample dataframe or data answerers would give correct response you are expecting. otherwise its hard to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxRecordsPerFile` as documented [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1182)

Sample Implementation

```
val df = spark.range(100).coalesce(1)
df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 50).save(filePath)
```

Comment: I use that option as well. Updated above. Problem is that for some qk's I could get partition more than 50 Gbs, when other would be few megabytes. And that slows down flush operations a lot, sometimes it causes OOM error, since that would be bigger than 2Gb during repartition stage.